# Replace of escape() and unescape() and the consequences for already stored strings

Tags: javascript, obsolete

I want to replace all the (deprecated) `escape()` and `unescape()` calls in our `Javascript` code  with `encodeURIComponent`,  `decodeURICompnent` or/and `encodeURI`, `decodeURI`.

The problem is, that our customers might have strings in their databases, which are already encoded by the deprecate "`escape()`"-Function, which might not be decoded correctly.

I guess many developers already had to deal with that problem.

One solution would be an update script, but I think there might be other approaches as well.

Any recommendations?

Best regards.

Comment: Unless it's Node, why were you even using Javascript to escape strings before database insertion in the first place? That sounds extremely unsafe and begging for a situation like this. Not to mention browsers might have slightly different implementations of it.

Comment: Yes, I know. I never implemented that behaviour...

Comment: Well then maybe you should take this opportunity to fix that now, instead of switching from one basically useless measure to a different basically useless measure.

Comment: ??? I want to fix it. That 's why I'm doing this post... Don't you see my problem? Customers stored strings in their DB with the deprecated escape(). I want to get rid of it. What's your suggestion?

Comment: @Amunium _even_ when it is node.